# Applications of Sard's theorem in full generality

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Sard's theorem states that the set of critical values of a map smooth $f: M \to N$ between smooth manifolds has measure zero.
However all applications I know of this theorem only use much weaker statements such as the density (or even only the existence) of regular values.

Does anybody know of an example of an application of Sards theorem (in differential topology/ geometry) that actually relies on the measure zero statement?

Comment: Full Sard's Theorem implies that if we take any finite or even countable family of functions, then there is a point which is regular for all of them. I vaguely recall seeing that applied before.

Comment: @Wojowu interesting, but I think this also follows from Baire's theorem if you replace "measure zero" with "nowhere dense".

Comment: In one of my papers, I needed to use the full strength of the Morse-Sard(-Federer) Theorem: If $f\colon M\to N$ is smooth and $A\subset M$ is the set of points where the rank of $f$ is less than $r\le\dim(N)$, then $f(A)$ has $r$-dimensional Hausdorff measure $0$ and hence has measure $0$ in the subset $Z\subset N$ of critical values of $f$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Come on, you can't just say that and not provide a reference!

Comment: The place I learned it was Federer's tome on Geometric Measure Theory. But you can google and find the [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem) for Morse-Sard on Wiki.

Comment: @Ted: I guess he was referring to your paper :)

Comment: Indeed I was. What happened to good old self-promotion?